# median and mode displaying -1

Tags: java, arrays, median, mode

Hey guys I have been learning coding recently and got an assignment of finding the mean, median and mode of a number of integers in an integer array. The issue that I am facing is that my median and mode displays -1 and I'm not too sure how to fix it, my "if user inputs no, print an error statement" is also not working and I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.
This is my code:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import static com.company.ProjectConstants.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = new int[MAXDATA];
        int counter = 0;
        boolean fileDone = false;
        boolean inputOk;
        String userInput;
        String theDataFile;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        genProgInfo();

        userInput = s.nextLine();
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

        while (!userInput.equals("yes") && (!userInput.equals("no"))) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Please input either yes or no: ");
            userInput = s.nextLine();
            userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
        }

        inputOk = userInput.equals("yes");

        initDataStorage(a);


        //do {
        try {
            // create file & scanner objects
            System.out.println("enter one of the file names:\nData10File.txt\nData30file.txt\nData35file.txt");
            theDataFile = s.next();
            theDataFile = theDataFile.toLowerCase();
            //fName = userInput;
            File f = new File(theDataFile);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

            // store file data in array, a
            for (int i = 0; i < MAXDATA; i++) {

                if (sc.hasNext()) {
                    a[i] = sc.nextInt();

                } else {

                    fileDone = true;
                    sc.close();
                    break;
                }

            }

            // print error message if file data exceeds the range of array
            if (!fileDone) {
                System.out.println("\n\tCAUTION: file has additional data, consider making array larger.");
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //} while (inputOk);


        s.close();

        for (int i=0; i<MAXDATA; i++) {
            if (a[i] != -1) {
                counter = a[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("counter: "+ counter);

        displayResults(calcMean(a), calcMedian(a), calcMode(a));


    }


    public static void initDataStorage(int[] data) {

        for (int i = 0; i < MAXDATA; i++) {
            data[i] = INVALID;
        }

    }


    public static double calcMean(int[] data) {


        int counter = 0;
        int mean;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < MAXDATA; i++) {
            if (data[i] != -1) {
                sum += data[i];
                counter++;
            }
        }


        mean = sum / counter;
        return mean;
    }


    public static double calcMedian(int[] data) {

        int middle = data.length / 2;
        if (data.length % 2 == 1) {
            return data[middle];
        } else {
            return (data[middle -1] + data[middle]) / 2.0;
        }
    }

    public static int calcMode(int[] data) {
        int mode = 0, maxCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
                if (data[j] == data[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                mode = data[i];

            }
        }


        return mode;
    }


    public static void genProgInfo() {

        System.out.println("This program will calculate the mean, median, and mode of a number of integers stored in the array");
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue?");

    }


    public static void displayResults(double mean, double median, int mode) {

        System.out.println("mean: " + mean);
        System.out.println("median: " + median);
        System.out.println("mode: " + mode);
    }


}
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the value of INVALID is -1 based on the other code I see and your description of what it outputs. Your array is of length MAXDATA and is initially filled with value INVALID in all elements. You then fill it with *n* values where *n* may be less than MAXDATA, and in that (probably common) case, many or even most of the values in the array are the INVALID value.

Your calcMean function is correctly skipping over the -1 (INVALID?) values and not including them in the calculation. Note however that the valid values are all at the beginning of the array and once you find an invalid value, you could break out of the loop in calcMean.

But the calcMedian and calcMode functions are not accounting for the invalid values. If *n* is significantly less than MAXDATA, then -1 probably really is the mode. Your calcMedian function has an additional problem as well, in that the (valid) data needs to be sorted in order for the "middle" or median value to be in the middle of the array.

Bonus question for your assignment: What if -1 occurs in the input file?